# Function from other file is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

I wrap by $(function) both files for running code when page is ready. But for some reasons calling function from first file in second file gives me error "ReferenceError: test is not defined".

First file:

```
$(function() {

    function test() {
        alert(1);
    }

});
```

Second file:

```
$(function() {

    test();

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because JavaScript scope, you can avoid this by using [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window) global object.

Adding your variables to [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window) object will make them global, so you can access them from anywhere.

First file:

```js
$(function() {

    window.test = function () {
        alert(1);
    }

});
```

Second file:

```js
$(function() {

    test();

});
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. But may you explain why JS doesn't find function in same scope?

Comment: @DIAMONDMAN your function `test` is not in the same scope, every function is JS have it own scope.

Comment: you saved my day !